# Eclipse Java Web Debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

HOw do I perform debugging in eclipse to debug my java web project??

Comment: Where is your web application running?

Comment: I created a test applicaion that runs on tomcat server(on localhost)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application **within** Eclipse, Select `Debug As --> Debug on Server` and choose your application server of your choice and run. Obviously, this can work only if you put breakpoints in your java source codes.

For presentation debugging (i.e. html, javascript, css, etc.), use Firebug or your browser debugger.

Comment: no I want to debug my servlet I inserted breakpoints on some places, And  also did "Select Debug As --> Debug on Server"

Comment: Then run your application on debug mode & go to your browser & browse your application till the http request hit your servlet. Eclipse will ask you to go on debug mode.